# Python PyQt: How Run While Loop Without Locking Main Dialog Window

Tags: python, pyqt

Pressing Ok button will run while_loop() method which prints some message on a screen.

While **while_loop()** method is running the main dialog becomes irresponsible. 
It's interesting that even after a dialog window is closed the function itself will be still running. Apparently that is not desired. When the dialog box is closed **while_loop()** method should be stopped as well. It would be great if running a while_loop() method wouldn't lock (make irresponsible) the main dialog window as well...

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run")
        ok_button.clicked.connect(self.OK)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(ok_button)       

        cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.cancel)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)

        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def myEvenListener(self):
        state=True
        while state:
            for i in range(10,100):
                time.sleep(i*0.01)
                print '.'*i

    def OK(self):
        self.myEvenListener()       

    def cancel(self):
        sys.exit()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(480, 320)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use thread to solve this problem. and so that your thread closes

```
import threading
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import psutil
import os

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

        ok_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Run")
        ok_button.clicked.connect(self.OK)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(ok_button)       

        cancel_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Cancel")
        cancel_button.clicked.connect(self.cancel)      
        self.main_layout.addWidget(cancel_button)

        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def myEvenListener(self,stop_event):
        state=True
        while state and not stop_event.isSet():
            for i in range(10,100):
                time.sleep(i*0.01)
                print '.'*i

    def OK(self):
        self.stop_event=threading.Event()
        self.c_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.myEvenListener, args=(self.stop_event,))
        self.c_thread.start()       

    def cancel(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        self.close()    

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(480, 320)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
main()


def kill_proc_tree(pid, including_parent=True):    
    parent = psutil.Process(pid)
    if including_parent:
        parent.kill()

me = os.getpid()
kill_proc_tree(me)
```